# How can I disable the startup/boot sound on a rooted Samsung Galaxy S5?

Tags: audio, boot, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I do not want any sound to play while the phone boots. A sound is being played while "Samsung" is displayed with an animation.

There is an app called "Silent Boot" in the Play store that mutes the phone during shutdown, which will supposedly mute the boot sound.
However, I'm looking for a solution that does not require an extra app, and that would work even with a lockup/battery-pull. The phone is rooted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With root access, simply rename, move, or delete the file: `/system/media/audio/ui/PowerOn.ogg`

This solution may work for other Samsung Galaxy models, and perhaps other makes as well, provided the sound file can be located.